# Multiple INSERT queries turned into one single query

Tags: sql

I've searched through Stackoverflow and nothing answers my question properly.

My question is how do you turn multiple INSERT queries into 1 single insert query.

More specific; https://gist.github.com/gregariousjb/e73fdf1489acbbb63651 this one. That's the query I need to understand how to make into a single one.

Sample;

```
INSERT INTO `creature` (`guid`, `id`, ...) 
     VALUES (1, 2843, ...);
INSERT INTO `creature` (`guid`, `id`, ...)
     VALUES (2, 7853, ...);
```

There's 1000 of these, that needs to be turned into a single one. I sincerely appreciate any help I can get on this.

Comment: Which database are you using?

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Sql Server try the following

```
Insert into table (columns..)
Values(values1,value2,...), 
    (values1,value2,...),
    (values1,value2,...),
    (values1,value2,...)
```

Answer (score 3):

In Mysql, do this (most popular databases have a similar syntax):

```
INSERT INTO mytable (col1, col2, col3, ...) VALUES
(1, 2843, 0, ...),
(2, 7853, 0, ...);
```

In most databases, you can do this:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (col1, col2, col3, ...)
SELECT 1, 2843, 0, ...
UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 7853, 0, ...;
```

In backward, behind-the-times databases, like Oracle, you must code this second option using the artificial single-rowed table DUAL:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (col1, col2, col3, ...)
SELECT 1, 2843, 0, ...
FRIM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 7853, 0, ...
FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: @Denis cryptic, but I got it :)

Comment: The second statement isn't exactly true. In Oracle (as of 10gR2), you'd have to do `SELECT 1, 2843, 0, ... FROM DUAL`, and in Jet SQL (aka, Access), there is no equivalent. For SQL Server, though, leaving off the FROM clause definitely works.

Comment: @cheran OK Thanks for reminding me. I've updated my answer to add this Oracle peculiarity.

Answer (score 2):

The closest is the shorthand version that requires the field list only once:

```
  INSERT INTO `creature` ( <field list> ) VALUES
    ( <value list> ),
    ( <value list> ),
    ( <value list> )
```